# Grails rendering plugin (pdf ) does not render Checkbox input

Tags: grails, pdf-generation, rendering

I've just installed grails rendering plugin and would like to use it for generating PDF files. I've created simple template, but this plugin does not render check input elements.
When i write the input as following :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myradio">
```

I have this error message :

```
Class
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException
Message
The element type "input" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</input>".
```

When i add end-tag as following :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myradio"></input>
```

i don't get any check element in PDF . 
I don't mean , i want to have check in interact mode , but, i want to have an image that seems as checkBox

Comment: Not sure how you can have check box in the rendered pdf, I use to solve the issue by using checkbox images, in that place, a checked check box image for checked check box and vice versa

Comment: thanks, however,  i will have the same pb because img tag is also a Singleton tag <img/> ; i try to add images by <img></img> but in vain

Comment: input is also a Single tag <input />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rendering plugin does not render image using img tag. You have to use rendering plugin's tags to render the image.

```
 <rendering:inlinePng bytes="${imageBytes}" class="some-class" />
```

and many more.

Please have a look in the [link](http://gpc.github.io/grails-rendering/docs/manual/guide/7.%20Inline%20Images.html).

[Grails Rendering Plugin - Reference Documentation](http://gpc.github.io/grails-rendering/docs/manual/)